# Error: trying to add members to group by Telegram ID

Tags: python, telethon

this is the code but its giving me error. maybe get by entity not working in this code.i have tried changing the entity type and everything else but that also doesnt works. i give parameters as required in the script but still it doesnt do anything but only gives me error"some error in adding".

```
    try:
        user_to_add = client.get_entity(int(user['user_id']))
        print(user_to_add)
        client(InviteToChannelRequest(entity, [user_to_add]))
        usr_id = user['user_id']
        print(f'{attempt}{g} Adding {usr_id}{rs}')
        print(f'{sleep}{g} Sleep 20s{rs}')
        time.sleep(20)
    except PeerFloodError:
        #time.sleep()
        os.system(f'del {file}')
        sys.exit(f'\n{error}{r} Aborted. Peer Flood Error{rs}')
    except UserPrivacyRestrictedError:
        print(f'{error}{r} User Privacy Restriction{rs}')
        continue
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(f'{error}{r} Aborted. Keyboard Interrupt{rs}')
        update_list(users, added_users)
        if not len(users) == 0:
            print(f'{info}{g} Remaining users logged to {file}')
            logger = Relog(users, file)
            logger.start()
    except:
        print(f'{error}{r} Some Other error in adding{rs}')
        continue
#os.system(f'del {file}')
input(f'{info}{g}Adding complete...Press enter to exit...')
sys.exit()
```

give me this error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Noni\Desktop\python\telegramscraper-main\addbyid1.py", line 90, in <module>
    user_to_add = client.get_entity(int(user['user_id']))
  File "C:\Users\Noni\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\telethon\sync.py", line 39, in syncified
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Noni\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 292, in get_entity
    inputs.append(await self.get_input_entity(x))
  File "C:\Users\Noni\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 466, in get_input_entity
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Could not find the input entity for PeerUser(user_id=807250194) (PeerUser). Please read https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/entities.html to find out more details.
```

Comment: very new to all this. this was my first question. which ones to remove? according to me i only have put those which tags could help. as the script is python, based on python telegram and made from telethon library with bot api. as i said i am new so try to help and enlighten me.

Comment: ok. thanks. seems that tag has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the error?

I think you know that you can't add more than 200 subscribers to the channel manually. Please check the current number of subscribers. If it is more than 200 your code will not work.

Comment: I am trying to add by id to a group. Full code which i am using is addbyid.py from https://github.com/DenizShabani/telegramscraper